# Testing access token filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-security

I have created a Bearer token creator and when i write its test, the test always fails and return nullPointerException what is the problem ?

Note: A bearer token syntax is like that [Bearer {someEncodedCharacter}].

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@SpringBootTest
public class JwtTokenFilterTest {

  @MockBean
  private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
  @MockBean
  private TokenManager tokenManagerTester;
  @MockBean
  private Authentication authentication;
  @MockBean
  private SecurityContext securityContext;
  @MockBean
  private HttpServletResponse httpResponse;
  @MockBean
  private FilterChain filterChain;
  @Test
  public void givenHttpServletRequestandHttpServletResponseandFilterChainDoFilterInternal()
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    String token="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhYmMxMjMiLCJpc3MiOiJ3d3cuYWJjLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTU5NDY0MTUzNywiZXhwIjoxNTk0NjQxODM3fQ.GHzVaQW_tvqo8HlDmoXzZ8WIYGcLHciLOSMFxsZUOsY";
    Mockito.when(httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization")).thenReturn("Bearer "+token);
    Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
    Mockito.when(tokenManagerTester.tokenValidate(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(tokenManagerTester
        .getUsernameToken(token))
        .thenReturn("abc123");


    JwtTokenFilter filter=new JwtTokenFilter();

    filter.doFilterInternal(httpRequest, httpResponse, filterChain);
    Mockito.verify(filterChain,Mockito.times(1));

  }


}
```

Here is the JwtfFilter:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {



    @Autowired
    private TokenManager tokenManager;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    @NotNull HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    @NotNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        /**
         * We are parsing our token in two pieces and we process the second
         * "Bearer hvs231asas2355"
         */
        final String authHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        /* */
        String username = null;
        String token = null;


        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.contains("Bearer")) {
            token = authHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = tokenManager.getUsernameToken(token);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            if (tokenManager.tokenValidate(token)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upassToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, new ArrayList<>());
                upassToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(upassToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse); 
    }
}
```

Note2: I think that if i controll the filterChain.dofilter i can see that the method works correct. For this reason i wrote the Mockito.verify(filterChain,Mockito.times(1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that i used MockBean instead of Mock.

```
  private static HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

  private static TokenManager tokenManagerTester;

  private static Authentication authentication;

  private static SecurityContext securityContext;

  private static HttpServletResponse httpResponse;

  private static FilterChain filterChain;
  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUp(){
    httpResponse = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    filterChain=mock(FilterChain.class);
    securityContext=mock(SecurityContext.class);
    authentication=mock(Authentication.class);
    tokenManagerTester=mock(TokenManager.class);
    httpRequest=mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
  }
```

Comment: please avoid defining mocked variables as static. Not the best practice. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **@SpringBootTest** or **@WebMvcTest** annotation at the top of your test class. That is why the dependency beans are not mocked by Spring.

Or you can use Mockito:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JwtTokenFilterTest {

  @Mock
  private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
  @Mock
  private TokenManager tokenManagerTester;
  @Mock
  private Authentication authentication;
  @Mock
  private SecurityContext securityContext;
  @Mock
  private HttpServletResponse httpResponse;
  @Mock
  private FilterChain filterChain;
  
  @InjectMocks
  private JwtTokenFilter filter=new JwtTokenFilter();
  
  @Test
  public void givenHttpServletRequestandHttpServletResponseandFilterChainDoFilterInternal()
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    String token="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhYmMxMjMiLCJpc3MiOiJ3d3cuYWJjLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTU5NDY0MTUzNywiZXhwIjoxNTk0NjQxODM3fQ.GHzVaQW_tvqo8HlDmoXzZ8WIYGcLHciLOSMFxsZUOsY";
    Mockito.when(httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization")).thenReturn("Bearer "+token);
    Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
    Mockito.when(tokenManagerTester.tokenValidate(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(tokenManagerTester
        .getUsernameToken(token))
        .thenReturn("abc123");
    filter.doFilterInternal(httpRequest, httpResponse, filterChain);
    Mockito.verify(filterChain,Mockito.times(1));

  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the result is still same. Adding those do not solve the problem.

Comment: @LeoS At which line exactly are you getting the Null Pointer Exception? Can u share the stacktrace in question?

Comment: i share it above but because of the pagination of the stackoverflow it stays right side, i fix it now.

Comment: @LeoS can u please write the whole test class, including the annotations you included at the top and imports.

Comment: fixed it also added imports.

Comment: Bro, you shouldnt add both annotations. And if you add WebMvcTest, you need to define all the configuration classes inside it.

Comment: if i add just @SpringBootTest still same btw.

Comment: And you are mocking everything, so you may want to avoid loading application context, using a MockitoJunitRunner and use Mock instead of MockBean

Comment: Can you send me the code of TokenManager and SecurityContextHolder (and all other classes required to compile) through https://friendpaste.com/ . I will set it up locally and give u the soln.

Comment: Can you give an example or fix my code ? I do not understand the difference that you  mentioned.

Comment: The thing is, because I dont have all the classes you are using, it is not compiling for me locally. However I added an approach with Mockito. Can u please give a try.